# C# XML - XPath Query Builder - Dynamically Create a Query

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to build a XPath Query Builder in order to have a generic code as portable as possible.

So far, this is what I came up with :

```
private static string XpathQueryBuilder (string NodeName,string AttributeName = null, string AttributeValue = null)
    {

        string XpathAttr = "";

        if (AttributeName != null)
            if (AttributeValue != null)
                XpathAttr = "[@" + AttributeName + "='" + AttributeValue + "']";
            else
                XpathAttr = "[@" + AttributeName + "='*']";
        return "//" + NodeName + XpathAttr;

    }
```

The problem I see with this method though is that if I have more than one attribute or node that I would like to look for, this function won't work. Is there a way to create an XPath Query dynamically that could theorically accept any number of attributes and/or Nodes.

My priority is on having a function that accepts more than one attribute and attribute value as this is the more likely case than more than one node.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why not pass a KeyValuePair<string,string>, pass a list and loop through it by appending the attributes?

Comment: That would be a good easy alternative instead of creating a custome Linq provider. I wasn't aware of the Key Pair mechanism. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary<string,string>` to make the function capable of receiving multiple attributes parameter :

```
private static string XpathQueryBuilder(string nodeName, Dictionary<string,string> attributes = null)
{
    string xpathAttr = "";
    if (attributes != null)
    {
        xpathAttr = 
            "[" + 
            String.Join(" and ", 
                    attributes.Select(o => 
                    {
                        var attrVal = o.Value ?? "*";
                        return "@" + o.Key + "='" + attrVal + "'";
                    })
            ) + "]";
    }

    return "//" + nodeName + xpathAttr;
}
```

---

**example usage :**

```
var node = "Root";
var attrs = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"foo", "bar"},
    {"baz", null},  
};
var result = XpathQueryBuilder(node, attrs);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4JymPa)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
//Root[@foo='bar' and @baz='*']
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using LINQ to XML?

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

String GUID = "something";

XElement profilesXel = XElement.Load("your xml file path");
XElement currProfile = (from el in profilesXel
                        where (String)el.Element("GUID") == GUID
                        select el).First();
```

....

Comment: Could you be more specific in your answer?  I am having a hard time trying to figure this out and I must be honest, I don't know where to begin in the Linq library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

It will allow you select any data that you want.

Also, if you need more generic solution, you can try to implement [your own LINQ Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158(v=vs.110).aspx) for that.

The second way is more complicated than the first one, but as a result you will have more generic solution that will provide access to your xml file by LINQ chains and expressions (lambda etc).

A few links with examples for help:

http://weblogs.asp.net/mehfuzh/writing-custom-linq-provider

http://fairwaytech.com/2013/03/writing-a-custom-linq-provider-with-re-linq/

http://jacopretorius.net/2010/01/implementing-a-custom-linq-provider.html

https://aashishkoirala.wordpress.com/2014/03/10/linq-provider-1/

Comment: Thank you for the links, I will definitely look into LINQ to XML library, but for now, it feels a little bit over what I feel I can manage so I'll go with the dictionnary method.

Comment: Sure, I'm not forcing you to jump into in right now. And I will be glad to help you with understating LINQ to XML. Or if you decided to implement your own provider - feel free to ask about it!